# Are arrow functions recommended in Jasmine Test cases?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

As per mocha documentation the use of arrow functions are discouraged.

https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions

Is this the same for Jasmine? I couldn't find any pointers on the topic in Jasmine documentation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a really very interesting article you should not miss:

- [Better Jasmine Tests With this](https://gist.github.com/traviskaufman/11131303#better-jasmine-tests-with-this)

And this is a cite:

> #### [The new, better way](https://gist.github.com/traviskaufman/11131303#the-new-better-way)
>
> For every test (and their beforeEach/afterEach hooks), jasmine sets
>   the receiver of each function to an initially empty object. This
>   object, which is called userContext within Jasmine's source code, can
>   have properties assigned to it, and gets blown away at the end of each
>   test. In an attempt to address the issues we were having, we recently
>   switched over to assigning variables to this object, rather than
>   declaring them within describe and then assigning them. So our
>   original code above now looked something like this:
>
> ```
> describe('views.Card', function() {
>   'use strict';
>
>   beforeEach(function() {
>     this.model = {};
>     this.view = new CardView(this.model);
>   });
>
>   describe('.render', function() {
>     beforeEach(function() {
>       this.model.title = 'An Article';
>       this.view.render();
>     });
>
>     it('creates a "cardTitle" h3 element set to the model\'s title', function() {
>       expect(this.view.$el.find('.cardTitle')).toContainText(this.model.title);
>     });
> ```

So, what does that all mean? Should we use arrow function with jasmine?

And the answer should be - keep arrow functions in your code, except of this combination

```
// could be arrow
describe("ListModel -", () =>
{
    // local context description
    interface IMyTestContext
    {
        items?: Heroe[];
        ...
    }
    // could be arrow
    describe("Test items ", () =>
    {
        // NOT AN ARROW - profit from Jasmine context passed as 'this'
        beforeEach(function()
        {
            var ctx: IMyTestContext = this.TestContext = {}; 
            // TODO do some defaults with context
            ...
        });

        // NOT AN ARROW - profit from Jasmine context passed as 'this'
        it("should ...", function()
        {
            var ctx: IMyTestContext = this.TestContext;
            // TODO ... test expecations
        ...
```

So, **`beforeEach()`** and **`it()`** **do NOT** use arrow - to profit from Jasmine context represented by **`this`**

we can also introduce a global call **`beforeEach`**

```
import * as something from "...";

beforeEach(function()
{
    this.TestContext = {};
});
```

and now context is always there for us so we do not have to re-create it:

```
describe("Track Changed items ", () =>
{
    // NOT AN ARROW - profit from Jasmine context passed as 'this'
    beforeEach(function()
    {                                              // created by global beforeEach above
        var ctx: IMyTestContext = this.TestContext;//  = {};
```

> Yes, that is really so amazing, that if a test runner will find some global `beforeEach` ... it will also run it before each test... awesome, is not it?

Comment: Yes, it's awesome. This is very good info. I have been swamped with variables in describe :(..

Comment: Great to see that, sir ;) ;) we are lucky guys, aren't we? ;)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.